# I don't understand these compile errors

Tags: c++

I can not compile, this program is giving me errors. I have already spend 3 days on it.

C:\unisa\COS1511\test.cpp
[Warning] In function `float calcAllowedPerChild(float)':

error C:\unisa\COS1511\test.cpp:26
invalid operands of types `float ()(float)` and `const float` to binary `operator<`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const float maxPerUnit = 20000.00;
//minPerChild include a standard gift consisting of a bath towel and facecloft
const float minPerChild = 100.00;
const float maxPerChild = 180.00;

//Depending on the amount the child may also get one or more of the fallowing:
const float TOOTHBRUSH = 29.95;
const float HIGHLIGHTERS = 25.99;
const float CRAYONS = 17.95;
const float NOTEBOOK = 12.95;
const float PEN = 9.99;

//You must add the function calcAllowebPerchild () here

float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren)

{

float allowedPerChild = maxPerUnit / nrChildren;

if ( allowedPerChild > maxPerChild || calcAllowedPerChild < minPerChild)

    return maxPerChild;
    else
    return minPerChild;

} 

int main ()
{

    float amtGift; //Allowed amount per child
    float amtSpendPerChild = 0.00; //actual amount spend per child
    float totalSpend = 0.00; //total spend for one orphanage
    float totalAll = 0.00; //total spend for all 4 orphanages
    int nrChildren;        //number of chldren per orphanage

    cout << "Enter the number of children: " << endl;
    cin >> nrChildren;
    amtGift = calcAllowedPerChild(nrChildren);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << endl << " Allowable amount per child    :R" << amtGift;
    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a semi colon on this line `float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);` that you probably don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);
                                          // ^ : Error - reomove it.
```

Function protoypes end with a `;` but not function definitions. Also take a look at the `if` statement condition -

```
if ( calcAllowedPerChild > maxPerChild || calcAllowedPerChild < minPerChild)
```

---

Since it is a homework, I will give you a hint upon the next error.

**Hint** : Every statement should end with a `;`. And now check inside your `calcAllowerPerChild` function.

```
if ( allowedPerChild > maxPerChild || calcAllowedPerChild < minPerChild)
                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Probably you
                                     // meant allowedPerChild. Change it.
```

Comment: Please help, now is giving three error:

 error C:\COS1511\test.cpp:26
expected `,' or `;' before "if"

 error C:\COS1511\test.cpp:29
expected primary-expression before "else"

 error C:\unisa\COS1511\test.cpp:29
expected `;' before "else"

Comment: @queos - Check the hint given.

Comment: thaks I think I am geting it now is one error remaining:  error C:\unisa\COS1511\test.cpp:26
invalid operands of types `float ()(float)' and `const float' to binary `operator<'

Comment: @queos - In C++, if you are using a varible, it should be declared and be accessed in the current scope. There is no variable called `calcAllowedPerChild` that is declared either in local scope or global scope. Before even starting to program, I recommend you to read a good book. You are making very basic mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

You have a ; at the end of your `calcAllowedPerChild` function.

Functions should look like:

```
void foo() {
    ... code ...
}
```

or:

```
void foo()
{
    ... code ...
}
```

depending on your coding style.

**Edit** - you also need to correct your spelling (maxPerChald) and declare `calcAllowedPerChild`:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild = maxPerUnit / nrChildren;
```

as well as changing the name of either your `calcAllowedPerChild` function or your `calcAllowedPerChild` variable. You can't have them both have the same name.

Comment: I have remove the ; at the end of calcAllowedPerChild function but still giving two error

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a `;` at the end of this function:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);
```

Fix that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking your semicolons - ensure that function declarations do not look like prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with `calcAllowedPerChild` - it should be:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild (float nrChildren)
{    
    float allowedPerChild = maxPerUnit / nrChildren;

    if (allowedPerChild > maxPerChild || allowedPerChild < minPerChild)
        return maxPerChild;
    else
        return minPerChild;
}
```

You also have a typo here:

```
const float maxPerChald = 180.00;
```

it should be:

```
const float maxPerChild = 180.00;
```

Comment: Thanks now I have change it as you said but still giving three error which are:

Comment: Please help, now is giving three error:

 error C:\COS1511\test.cpp:26
expected `,' or `;' before "if"

 error C:\COS1511\test.cpp:29
expected primary-expression before "else"

 error C:\unisa\COS1511\test.cpp:29
expected `;' before "else"

Comment: @queos: you should have copied and pasted the code above - you still have one error in your code - change `if ( allowedPerChild > maxPerChild || calcAllowedPerChild < minPerChild)` to `if ( allowedPerChild > maxPerChild || allowedPerChild < minPerChild)`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);
```

should not have the semicolon at the end. It should be:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren)
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, yeah, you have an extra ';' in your function definition:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);
```

Just get rid of the semicolon at the end of the line there.  That's what the compiler was trying to tell you when it said you have an extra semicolon on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon `;` at the end of `float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);`
Function definitions do not end with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Is this typo in your code?

```
const float maxPerChald = 180.00;
```

Remove the semicolon after this line:

```
float calcAllowedPerChild ( float nrChildren);
```